# Wi-Fi 6 AX210/AX211/AX411 160MHz no longer available

Tags: networking, drivers, 22.04, iwlwifi

My Wi-Fi 6 AX210/AX211/AX411 160MHz adapter:

```
$ sudo lshw -class network
  *-network                 
       description: Network controller
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX210/AX211/AX411 160MHz
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:5c:00.0
       version: 1a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
       resources: irq:19 memory:86200000-86203fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 10
       bus info: usb@2:3.2
       logical name: enx9cebe881680f
       serial: 9c:eb:e8:81:68:0f
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.12.13 duplex=full firmware=rtl8153b-2 v1 10/23/19 ip=192.168.31.153 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
```

```
$ lspci | grep Network
5c:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX210/AX211/AX411 160MHz (rev 1a)
```

stopped working on Ubuntu 22.04:

```
$ uname -a
Linux xxx 5.15.0-50-generic #56-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 20 13:23:26 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

On `dmsg` I have:

```
[   12.119898] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x7663, CPU2 Status: 0xb03
[   12.119921] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: UMAC PC: 0x8047f600
[   12.119932] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: LMAC PC: 0x0
[   12.119933] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[   12.120044] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 66.f1c864e0.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-66.ucode
[   12.120046] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x00000000 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT          
[   12.120047] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status0
[   12.120048] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[   12.120048] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x00000000 | branchlink2
[   12.120049] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x00000000 | interruptlink1
[   12.120050] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x00000000 | interruptlink2
[   12.120050] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x00000000 | data1
[   12.120051] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x00000000 | data2
[   12.120051] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x00000000 | data3
[   12.120052] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x00000000 | beacon time
[   12.120053] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf low
[   12.120053] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[   12.120054] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[   12.120054] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp2
[   12.120055] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x00000000 | uCode revision type
[   12.120056] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x00000000 | uCode version major
[   12.120056] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x00000000 | uCode version minor
[   12.120057] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x00000000 | hw version
[   12.120057] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x00000000 | board version
[   12.120058] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x00000000 | hcmd
[   12.120059] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr0
[   12.120059] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr1
[   12.120060] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr2
[   12.120060] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr3
[   12.120061] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr4
[   12.120061] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
[   12.120062] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x00000000 | wait_event
[   12.120063] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
[   12.120063] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
[   12.120064] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[   12.120064] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[   12.120065] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x00000000 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[   12.120066] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[   12.120066] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x00000000 | flow_handler
[   12.120148] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[   12.120148] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: Transport status: 0x00000042, valid: 7
[   12.120149] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x201013F2 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[   12.120150] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[   12.120151] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x8045DFC6 | umac branchlink2
[   12.120151] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink1
[   12.120152] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
[   12.120153] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x0000000C | umac data1
[   12.120153] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x00040000 | umac data2
[   12.120154] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data3
[   12.120154] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x00000042 | umac major
[   12.120155] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0xF1C864E0 | umac minor
[   12.120156] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x00012298 | frame pointer
[   12.120156] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0xC0887F34 | stack pointer
[   12.120157] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x00000000 | last host cmd
[   12.120158] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[   12.120213] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: IML/ROM dump:
[   12.120214] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x00000B03 | IML/ROM error/state
[   12.120224] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x00007663 | IML/ROM data1
[   12.120234] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x00000080 | IML/ROM WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0
[   12.120241] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: Fseq Registers:
[   12.120244] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x60000100 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[   12.120247] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x00440005 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[   12.120250] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x00080009 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[   12.120253] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x0000A652 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[   12.120257] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x00000002 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[   12.120260] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[   12.120263] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x00400410 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[   12.120270] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x00400410 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[   12.120273] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x00400410 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   12.120278] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x00400410 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   12.120285] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x00009061 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[   12.120291] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: 0x00000061 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[   12.120293] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[   12.120295] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[   13.620071] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[   13.633363] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: retry init count 2
```

What I can do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved in this way:

```
cd /lib/firmware
sudo mv iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-66.ucode iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-66.ucode.b
sudo reboot
```